# How to execute runCommand with Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I am using Node.js and Mongoose to access my MongoDB. I am using a model that stores some geo coordinates. I have them indexed and everything seems to work as expected. What I am trying to do is to retrieve the most near things from my request. On the MongoDB console I do something like this:

```
distances = db.runCommand({ geoNear : "deals", near : [11.252, 14.141], spherical : true, maxDistance : 300  }).results
```

However, I am not sure how to do this with Mongoose. Here is more information about the command I am trying to use: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

Thanks,
Jose

Answer (score 5):

First of all there is not yet a convenience wrapper to use geoNear with Mongoose directly (given that you want to read the calculated distance).

But since Mongoose collections [proxies all collection methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) from the native [MongoDB native driver](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/) you can just use their [geoNear method](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#geonear), though you have to give up a little bit of convenience you might expect from Mongoose and in my findings the error handling was a little bit different.

Anyway, this is how you could use said API:

```
YourModel.collection.geoNear(lon, lat, {spherical: true, maxDistance: d}, function(err, docs) {
  if (docs.results.length == 1) {
    var distance = docs.results[0].dis;
    var match = docs.results[0].obj;
  }
});
```

Please refer to the docs for correct error handling and [how to calculate the distances](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-SphericalExample).

Answer (score 1):

```
YourModel.db.db.executeDbCommand({geoNear : "locations", near : [11.252,14.141], spherical: true }, function(err,res) { console.log(res.documents[0].results)});
```

node 0.6.6,
mongoose@2.4.9,
mongodb version v2.0.2

its a bit hacky and could change.

Comment: This no longer works in 3.6x. Looking through the API docs, I don't see anything comparable.  Do you know of another way to accomplish this?

Comment: YourModel.db.db.command({geoNear : "locations", near : [11.252,14.141], spherical: true }, function(err,res) { console.log(res.documents[0].results)});

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Mongoose supports `runCommand` right now. You would be better off using the geospatial options using the `find` method e.g. >

```
db.places.find( { location : { $near : [50,50] , $maxDistance : 300 } } )
```

Comment: But this does not return me the distance which I would like to have! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this should work!! Referrence URL :
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html

// Legacy point

```
Model.geoNear([1,3], { maxDistance : 5, spherical : true }, function(err, results, stats) {
   console.log(results);
});
```

// geoJson

```
var point = { type : "Point", coordinates : [9,9] };
Model.geoNear(point, { maxDistance : 5, spherical : true }, function(err, results, stats) {
   console.log(results);
});
```